# Sticker album - probability of getting a new sticker

Tags: probability

Suppose we have a sticker album for $m$ stickers. Suppose that we buy the stickers one by one and, **each time a sticker of a new type is obtained(i.e, that sticker was not taken before)**, it has type $i$ with probability $p_i$, $i=1,...,m$. If you adquires your $n-th$ sticker, what is the probability that it is a new one?

**My first attempt:**

$P($sticker has type $i|$it is new$) = p_i = P($sticker is new and has type $i)$ $\frac{1}{P(it\;is\;new)}$. Thus

$P(n-th$ sticker is new$)$ = $P(n-th$ sticker is new and has type $i)\frac{1}{p_i}$=

= $P(n-th$sticker is new$|type\;i)P(type\;i)\frac{1}{p_i}$

I'm not sure if it is a correct approach and I couldn't find $P(n-th$ sticker is new|type i$)$.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** I think that Henry wrong interpreted the question: $p_i$ is not the probability that a sticker caught have type i, but it is the probability that, given that the sticker is new (that is, I have a space for it on the album), the sticker have type i. As I wrote before: $P($sticker have type i|it is new$)=p_i$

Comment: Every type of sticker is a new type of sticker exactly once eventually, suggesting in the alternative interpretation that $p_i=\dfrac{1}{m}$ for all $i$ even if the types have different probabilities, where $m$ is the total number of types.  This makes the question unanswerable.

Answer (score 1):

The probability that the $n$th sticker is of type $i$ is $p_i$.

The probability that the previous $n-1$ stickers were not of type $i$ is $(1-p_i)^{n-1}$.

So the probability that the $n$th sticker is new is $\sum_i p_i (1-p_i)^{n-1}.$

Comment: the probability that the $n-1$ previous stickers were not of type $i$ is not (1-p_i), since this event is not the complementar of the event "sticker has type i | it is new "

Comment: When I said $(1-p_i)^{n-1}$, this was just the probability of $n-1$ non-$i$-type stickers.  This is independent of the type of the $n$th sticker

Comment: Henry, but $p_i$ is the probability of a sticker caught have the type i, **given that** it is a new type sticker. The probability of we take a sticker of type $i$ without this condition is $\frac{1}{m}$

Comment: Suppose you have two types of stickers, one of which is three times as common as the other: what are the values of $p_i$? $\frac34$ and $\frac14$? $\frac12$ and $\frac12$? Something else?